# How can I eliminate this repeated Java Runtime Environment (JRE) pop-up window?

Tags: java

This window has been popping up repeatedly:[image: repeated]

I was sure that I already had the latest version of Java installed, but to verify I went here: https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

And sure enough I have the latest JRE.
[image]

Then I went and followed the directions here to find the JRE via my command line:
https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml#cmdline
which says to enter:

> $ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version

and the terminal output was:

> java version "1.8.0_25"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)`

Can anyone help me identify what I'm doing wrong here?  I definitely have Java.

Comment: the command to find JRE in termianl is just "java version"

Comment: It is `java -version` you need a space and a `-`

Comment: right. `$java -version`... the output was:
`No Java runtime present, requesting install.`

Comment: Would the problem simply be that I don't have the Java Developer Kit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed the Java Developer Kit and that fixed the problem. I'm not sure why that was needed.