# What causes the pop-up "To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment"

Tags: macos, java, startup

On OSX Yosemite an annoying pop-up comes up quite often saying:

> To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment

I know the [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166793/how-can-i-eliminate-this-repeated-java-runtime-environment-jre-pop-up-window) is to install java; however I'm wondering what's the cause for that.

A quick `ps -axww` tells me:

```
13218   ??  S      0:00.29 /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Download Java Components.app/Contents/MacOS/Download Java Components
```

I dug around and I found that there is a LaunchDaemon that references this in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.java.InstallOnDemand.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.java.InstallOnDemandAgent</string>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.java.installondemand</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Download Java Components.app/Contents/MacOS/Download Java Components</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Does anyone know what is the purpose of all this? The pop-up appears at random times, which makes me think there's a background daemon that demands Java to run but I could not find any source for this behaviour.

Comment: "To view this web content" -> have a look at your browser tabs/windows.

Comment: @patrix: the odd thing is that the pop-up appears regardless of what tabs I  have open, or whether I've just opened a tab or not.

Comment: There may be a browser plugin or an app launched @ startup which requires Java. A bit of googling finds some users get this with a Facebook video chat plugin, a baseball game streaming plugin, etc. If you have installed Java recently, and you still get these messages, it is possible you followed the wrong link to a version that has glitches under Yosemite. You need to find the correct version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my sister this was caused by Facebook videochat. We debugged quite randomly, and could not find a way to tell what triggered this dialog; like indeed `ps` did not show what started it. But [the following Apple Support Communities post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602999) explained how to find it by trial and error:

> Here are the steps I used to correct, as even after removal from Launch control it kept returning on reboot:
>
> 1. Open a Terminal Prompt
> 2. Show non Apple startup Agents. At $ execute
>
>    ```
>    launchctl list | grep -v apple
>    ```
>
>    This will look something like the following.
>
>    ```
>    PID Status Label
>    -   0      org.openbsd.ssh-agent
>    282 0      com.symantec.symsecondarylaunch.application
>    274 0      com.symantec.quickmenu.application
>    -   0      com.google.keystone.system.agent
>    -   0      com.valvesoftware.steamclean
>    -   0      com.oracle.java.Java-Updater
>    276 0      com.Logitech.Control Center.Daemon
>    302 0      com.google.Chrome.62228
>    -   1      com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.updater
>    295 0      com.symantec.scannotification.application
>    -   0      net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.LaunchAtLogin
>    275 0      com.symantec.savdiskmountnotify.application
>    317 0      net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.119880
>    ```
>
>    One of the returned items is likely your issue, mine was also `com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.updater`
> 3. Change to the Agents directory, `cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents/`
> 4. I also had to remove the actual agent files, as it kept re-appearing on reboot. You can view those on your system and remove. List out the items in directory: `ls`
>
>    ```
>    SharedServices.Agent.plist
>    com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.plist
>    com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist
>    net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.LaunchAtLogin.plist
>    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist
>    ```
> 5. From `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` execute
>
>    ```
>    rm com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.plist
>    ```
> 6. Also remove from Launch control with
>
>    ```
>    launchctl remove com.facebook.videochat.USERNAME.updater
>    ```
> 7. Exit and reboot

If I recall correctly then this videochat thing might also have been a plugin in her browser, which we then already removed earlier.