# What causes the repeated popup? after installing yosemite

Tags: macos, error, bug

Bug. What could be the cause/s of the repeated popup? after installing yosemite. Emphasis here on different theories about what actually causes the repeated interruptions of the popup.

There have been solutions for stopping the repeated popup. This is the question of cause/s and triggers.

a) Triggers? What triggers are there that activate the popup each time?

b) Cause/s ?  What actually causes it?

c) Different theories? How do varied notions of what actually causes it differ?

```
__________ transcribed popup ____________________
[icon. cup of coffee and two arrows curving around cup]
To view this web content, you need to
install the  Java Runtime Environment
Click "More Info..." to visit the website for the Java
Runtime Environment
[ More Info... ] [ OK ]
```

Comment: See [What causes the pop-up “To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment”](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175800/what-causes-the-pop-up-to-view-this-web-content-you-need-to-install-the-java-r).

Answer (score 2):

There is a stub executable for Java. This is what it looks like.

[image]

It exists to get you to install a specific version of the framework since Apple doesn't bundle it with their computer.

Think of this as an "install flash player" message, but for the operating system as opposed to a browser plug in.

No bug, this is how things are designed. If you see it more than once, then you either are calling programs that want you to install Java or you didn't install the tool completely.

See http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_10_10.xml and the general Mac FAQ at the bottom of the page from the link above.

Comment: Compare the transcribed popup in the first message with the popup in the second message.

Comment: @theszak The pop up depends on the versions. I don't have a 10.10 mac handy so someone will have to run java from terminal and/or get the OP picture up. It's almost certainly an installation issue, though. If you quit all web browsers and then type `java` in terminal.app, what do you see?

Comment: It's a different popup than the popup transcribed here originally Aug 15 at 9:34

Comment: Just for future reference: I don't think the messages differ per version, as it also refers to downloading a JDK versus a JRE. (As for the JRE-message, see [What causes the pop-up “To view this web content, you need to install the Java Runtime Environment”](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175800/what-causes-the-pop-up-to-view-this-web-content-you-need-to-install-the-java-r).)